# Python selenium - WebDriverException: target frame detached - for Login button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to automate login to the website https://research.axiscapital.co.in/.
I am able to add username and password. I have also automated solving the captcha. But after it solves the captcha, I am unable to click the login button. I get the **WebDriverException: target frame detached** exception. I am adding the code below (without the real username and password) for assistance.

NOTE: As soon as the captcha verification expires, the login button becomes clickable again. Kindly help me with it.

```
import requests
import time
import os
# Added for Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# TO MAKE THE SCRAPING FASTER
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("https://research.axiscapital.co.in/")

filename = '1.mp3'
delayTime = 2
googleIBMLink = 'https://speech-to-text-demo.ng.bluemix.net/'
audioToTextDelay = 10


def audioToText(mp3Path):
    print("1")
    driver.execute_script('''window.open("","_blank");''')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    print("2")
    driver.get(googleIBMLink)
    delayTime = 10
    # Upload file
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3")
    # Upload file
    time.sleep(1)
    root = driver.find_element_by_id('root').find_elements_by_class_name('dropzone _container _container_large')
    btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/input')
    btn.send_keys('D:\\blogs\\1.mp3')
    # Audio to text is processing
    time.sleep(delayTime)
    #btn.send_keys(path)
    print("4")
    # Audio to text is processing
    time.sleep(audioToTextDelay)
    print("5")
    text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[7]/div/div/div').find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
    print("5.1")
    result = " ".join( [ each.text for each in text ] )
    print("6")
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    print("7")
    return result
def saveFile(content,filename):
    with open(filename, "wb") as handle:
        for data in content.iter_content():
            handle.write(data)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,60)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="Username"]'))).send_keys(username)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="Password"]'))).send_keys(password)

time.sleep(1)
googleClass = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('g-recaptcha')[0]
time.sleep(2)
outeriframe = googleClass.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
time.sleep(1)
outeriframe.click()
time.sleep(2)

allIframesLen = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
time.sleep(1)
audioBtnFound = False
audioBtnIndex = -1

for index in range(len(allIframesLen)):
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[index]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    driver.implicitly_wait(delayTime)
    try:
        audioBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-audio-button') or driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-anchor')
        audioBtn.click()
        audioBtnFound = True
        audioBtnIndex = index
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass

if audioBtnFound:
    try:
        while True:
            href = driver.find_element_by_id('audio-source').get_attribute('src')
            response = requests.get(href, stream=True)
            saveFile(response,filename)
            response = audioToText(os.getcwd() + '/' + filename)
            print(response)
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[audioBtnIndex]
            driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
            inputbtn = driver.find_element_by_id('audio-response')
            inputbtn.send_keys(response)
            inputbtn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(2)
            
            errorMsg = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rc-audiochallenge-error-message')[0]
            if errorMsg.text == "" or errorMsg.value_of_css_property('display') == 'none':
                print("Success")
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Caught. Need to change proxy now')
else:
    print('Button not found. This should not happen.')


time.sleep(4)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Login"]'))).click()
```

Comment: I will not be able to test the code, but looking at the error it seems like it's related to switching frames, please check if you're switching back to the original frame after completing the captcha verification, and then try clicking on the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to switch to default context after successfully completing the captcha.

put `driver.switch_to.default_content()` before `break`.

Edit: the success block would look like this.

```py
                print("Success")
                driver.switch_to.default_content()
                break
```